# How is `soljson.js` created from Solidity repository

Tags: solidity, evm, solc, solcjs

In the official Solidity GitHub repo, under the releases section you can download the source code, binaries and the `soljson.js` file. How is the file generated and is it able to be generated by building the source?

Official Solidity GitHub Releases: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases